# Out of stock product not show on list page in magento2

Tags: magento2

how show Out of stock product not show on list page in magento2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show the out of stock products in your website by setting up "Display Out of Stock Products" to Yes. You can enable it by following steps:

> 1. Goto Store -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Inventory
> 2. Then set "Display Out of Stock Products" to Yes

Refer screenshot:
[image]

Comment: but this show with direct url not on category pages list page

Comment: This will show on each page not only product page. It should also show out of stock products on product list, widgets etc.